# C++: std::chrono or boost::chrono

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++-chrono

I'm doing some benchmarking in my code and I'm trying to figure out if I should use the standard version of chrono or the original one provided by Boost.
I started using the standard one because I wanted to try it out, and noticed that for example it doesn't provide io functions like the chrono provided by Boost does.
So, regarding chrono and in general, should I use Boost libraries or their standard library counterparts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on what do you want to achieve.
C++ chrono pros:

1. Better understandability (more users know standard library than boost)
2. Better portability (in case you have decided to use c++11)
3. Maybe it will work faster.
4. Don't add additional dependencies to project.

Boost chrono pros:

1. Works for c++03
2. Provides more functionality.

So, if you don't need that additional io functions and don't need c++03 support, use standard library.

Comment: +1 for good overview, I myself would use cheesy "use std::chrono when possible, boost::chrono when you have to"

Comment: (1) What interface part is better understandable in `std::chrono` than in `boost::chrono`? (2) `boost::chrono` is definitely *more* portable than `std::chrono`, as it works with wider range of compilers. (3) It's not quite clear what you mean by stating that `std::chrono` "will work faster".  The bottom line seems to be: additional dependency vs portability&functionality.

Comment: @IgorR. (1) Because you don't have to read boost documentation to understand it. (2) If you already use c++11, there must be `std::chrono` and there may not be boost at all for this architecture/compiler. (3) Std is provided by a compiler and usually uses the best implementation available for this platform. Boost may use some general implementation for some rare/unsupported compilers.

Comment: Depends on your platform! Unfortunately MSVC typedefs the high_resolution_clock to the system_clock (lazy bastards!). In other words, forget about measuring times below 1ms in Windows just with `#include <chrono>` . With `<boost/chrono.hpp>` you can though.